Springboot MultipartFile response includes invalid json "inputStream" with no value
I am using Springboot to return a MultipartFile as my response for an endpoint.
        MultipartFile file = new MockMultipartFile(
            imageUploadResponse.getKey(), 
            imageUploadResponse.getKey(), 
            imageUploadResponse.getMimeType(), 
            imageUploadResponse.getInputStream()
        );
        return new ResponseEntity<>(file, headers, HttpStatus.OK);

However, the JSON returned to the client looks like this:
{ ..., "inputStream" }

Which is invalid JSON and breaks my $.ajax request. How do I fix this issue?

Returning a MultipartFile directly in a Spring Boot response will not work as you expect because MultipartFile is not a serializable object, and Spring attempts to serialize it into JSON.
Instead, you can stream the file content directly in the response. Here’s how you can do it:

Change the Return Type: Instead of returning a MultipartFile, return
a ResponseEntity with the byte array of the file or an InputStream.
Set the Appropriate Headers: Ensure you set the correct content type
and any other necessary headers.


@RestController
public class YourController {

    @GetMapping("/your-endpoint")
    public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getFile() {
        // Simulating your image upload response
        ImageUploadResponse imageUploadResponse = ...; // Get your imageUploadResponse

        InputStream inputStream = imageUploadResponse.getInputStream();
        String fileName = imageUploadResponse.getKey();
        String mimeType = imageUploadResponse.getMimeType();

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, mimeType);

        InputStreamResource resource = new InputStreamResource(inputStream);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(resource, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}


Explanation:

InputStreamResource: This allows you to send an InputStream as a response body, which is suitable for file downloads.
Headers: You can set headers such as Content-Disposition to specify how the file should be handled by the client (download,
inline, etc.).
Content-Type: Make sure you set the correct MIME type for the file.


The issue was MockMultipartFile has a getter that does not serialize properly.

    @Override
    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(this.content);
    }


I solved it by extending MockMultipartFile
public class MultipartFileResponse extends MockMultipartFile {

  public MultipartFileResponse(String name, String originalFilename, String contentType, InputStream contentStream)
      throws IOException {
    super(name, originalFilename, contentType, contentStream);
  }

  // Parent class getInputStream is not serializable and
  // we don't need it, so we override and return null.
  @Override 
  public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
    return null;
  }
  
}

Now inputStream is null in the JSON response, instead of a key with a missing value.
